# How to get the $route service for the reload

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the $rout to do

```
$scope.reloadRoute = function() {
    $route.reload();
};
```

In all the examples that I found I need to load the ngRoute module
so I added the angular-route.min.js to my index.html and added ngRoute

```
var app = angular.module('gifts_and_parties', ['smart-table','ngRoute'])
```

but then my app crashes.

Comment: hi are you using ui-router or native routing ?

Comment: have you included it in the index.html file?

Comment: you didn't include $route as dependencies in controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be you are not injecting `$route` in your `controller`, also check whether you including `angular-route` in your index.html

```
Mypp.controller('Ctrl', [
    '$scope', '$route',
    function($scope,$route) {
         $route.reload();
     };
    }
]);
```

Secondly if you want to re-load the entire page, you might want to use `$window.location.reload();`

Comment: I did that and now the app crashes because (the error) is not the "AboutCtrl" (in your example - 'Ctrl') is undefined.
Before that I just had a function:
function AboutCtrl($scope, $http, $location)

Comment: About the second idea: $window.location.reload();
It doesn't recognize $window.
When I try: window.location.reload, it relads the main page (I don't want that).